# Upgrading Magento 1.6.1 to 1.7.0 save custom module

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.7

When I upgraded Magento, the AheadWorks module was disabled.

When saving on admin, System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> then click Save Config

> An error occurred while saving this configuration: Notice: Trying to
>   get property of non-object in
>   MAGENTO_ROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
>   on line 135

I've been searching in many times to find the solution but i got nothing.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=13819

How to fix that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find the following lines of code around line 135 of `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php`:

```
$backendClass = $fieldConfig->backend_model;
if (!$backendClass) {
    $backendClass = 'core/config_data';
}
```

and replace it by:

```
if (isset($fieldConfig->backend_model)) {
    $backendClass = $fieldConfig->backend_model;
}
if (!isset($backendClass)) {
    $backendClass = 'core/config_data';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

MagePsyco is correct, the issue is with the code at line 135 of `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php`:

```
$backendClass = $fieldConfig->backend_model;
if (!$backendClass) {
    $backendClass = 'core/config_data';
}
```

The issue with the fix MagePsyco suggests in his answer is that the code is executed in a loop.  Once it encounters an attribute with a backend model the $backlendModel variable isn't reset back to `core/config_data` again.  So for example on the System page of the System Configuration screen the "Installed Currencies" attribute has a backend model defined, but subsequent attributes don't.  This causes the _afterSave method from `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Locale` to be run on all of the subsequent attributes (which will fail).

A better solution is the version of this code that can be found in 1.8 alpha releases:

```
$backendClass = (isset($fieldConfig->backend_model))? $fieldConfig->backend_model : false;
if (!$backendClass) {
    $backendClass = 'core/config_data';
}
```

This takes care of all null/false/empty issues and ensures the $backendModel variable always contains a valid value.  This also suggests that the issue should be resolved and no patching is required once 1.8 is released.

Answer (score 2):

You can also turn off Magento's developer mode. I'm not a big fan of modifying the core (or having to extend it), so for the lazy, just disabling/enabling `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` as needed is the easiest solution until it's fixed.